# How can i use this kind of var in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The Problem is in the var a I have created

```
<script>
$( "#EDITsave" ).click(function() {
  var a = parseInt(window.id.charAt(window.id.length-1)) //a gets parsed correctly but nothing happens in ajax until i set a number myself
  console.log(a) 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "text",
    url: "edit.php",
    data: {
      inputID: a, 
      inputtxt:   //issue is in 'a' here! 
        document.getElementById("editinputtext").value
      },
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP: // PHP CODE FOR AJAX

```
$inputID = $_POST['inputID'];

$inputtxt = $_POST['inputtxt'];


$sql = "UPDATE Contributions SET inputtxt = '$inputtxt'  WHERE inputID   = $inputID";

if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $connection->error;
 }

$connection->close();

?>
```

Comment: Please show the part of edit.php that is receiving the data.

Comment: you have a serious XSS security whole as of right now.

Comment: the code has been uploaded

Comment: dont  allow POST data to be sent to your SQL database unchecked, or someone can simpy post '%' as the input ID and affect all IDs

Comment: Don't rely on javascript's automatic semicolon insertion.